# Display single column value of mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I get a single column value from mysqli? The result should be single row with only one column.

This is what I have tried:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(`userid`) FROM `user`";
$rlt = mysqli_query($this->db, $query);
echo $rlt['userid'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not fetching the row after executing the query:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(`userid`) FROM `user'";
$rlt = mysqli_query($this->db,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($this->db, $rlt);
echo $row[0];
```

The alternative would be to use an alias for the computed field and use `fetch_assoc`:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(`userid`) as `maxid` FROM `user'";
$rlt = mysqli_query($this->db,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->db, $rlt);
echo $row['maxid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try with create alias and fetch result after query execution also your quote of `user'` looking wrong

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(`userid`) as userid  FROM `user`";
$rlt = mysqli_query($this->db,$query);
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rlt);
echo $r['userid'];
```

or fetch only one row like:-

```
$r = mysqli_fetch_row($this->db, $rlt);
echo $r[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create `alias` here.

Use this one:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(`userid`) as Max_Userid  FROM `user'";
$rlt = mysqli_query($this->db,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->db, $rlt);
echo $row['Max_Userid'];
```

**Note:** Always use alias when you use mysql function in query with fields.